# Time complexity comparisons

Tags: big-o, time-complexity

[image: Time complexity]

I'm confused as to how f(n) can be O(g(n)), theta(g(n)) and omega(g(n)). Could someone help explain?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for [http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact each function that is of theta `g(n)` will be of O(g(n)) and omega(g(n)). The simplified definition is that f(n) is in Theta(g(n)) if it grows precisely as fast as g(n), while f(n) is in O(g(n)) if it grows no faster than g(n) and is in Omega(g(n)) if it grows no slower than g(n)(all there definitions hold for sufficiently large n). Thus when the speed at which f(n) and g(n) are the same both the conditions for omega and O hold.

As for why f(n) is in Theta(g(n)) - try dividing the two functions and analyzing the fraction when `n` grows to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest and straightforward way to solve such a question, you should use the Limit Method Process like the following:

[image]